# Is it possible to use something like c#'s stackalloc in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

In C# it is possible to allocate an array of items on the stack using stackalloc:

```
int* integerArray = stackalloc int[n];
```

Two things to note:
1- n does not seem to be a compile-time constant and 
2- this produces "localloc" IL instruction, whose description says

> "Allocates a certain number of bytes from the *local dynamic memory
>   pool* and pushes the address (a transient pointer, type *) of the
>   first allocated byte onto the evaluation stack."

The question is, how can I achieve this effect in C++/CLI code?

I certainly know how to allocate a *native* stack-based array (of both the C and C++ varieties), but both of those require the array size to be a compile-time constant.  I am not 100% sure I understand what a *local dynamic memory pool* is, but ***I would like to know how to produce the equivalent IL from C++/CLI as is produced by the C# stackalloc code quoted above.***

My question is unique from the "possible duplicate" tag because I am asking specifically about C++/CLI with an IL target.  I already know how to do this in native C++.  I am asking what construct I can use in C++/CLI to produce intermediate language output equivalent to what is produced by the C# stackalloc facilities.  This is *not* a question relevant to standard C++ but *specific* to C++/CLI.

Comment: Not a duplicate: I am asking about C++/CLI not native C++.  I want to produce IL that is equivalent to a construct exposed by the C# language in C++/CLI, not in native C++.

Comment: Down voter care to comment?

Comment: Also read about [Stack Semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177191.aspx)

Comment: No special syntax is necessary, you can use `_malloca()` like you can in a native C++ program.  Or for that matter simply declare an unmanaged array (like char[42]), it lives on the stack.

Comment: @Hans -- does _malloca() produce IL code or native code?  I am writing this to be have some parts of its IL code extracted and inserted into a purely managed (though not necessarily verifiable) assembly.  I don't want to have any dependencies to native libraries (like the C run time).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: I suppose you could think of it as being somewhat chameleon like.  In my defense, I did state: "I would like to know how to produce the equivalent IL from C++/CLI as is produced by the C# stackalloc code quoted above".

Comment: Whether `n` is a compiler time constant is related to the definition of `n`. You don't want a dynamic array of size `n` on the stack. If n is 1000000, you'll get a stack overflow